# iOS CF data structures vs NS data structures

Tags: iphone, ios, data-structures

I was wondering what are exactly the differences between CF data structures (CFArray, CFDictionary, etc) and NS data structures (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc..). I've been using mostly NS classes, yet I found that CF classes have better performance and have some advantage over NS classes. I would appreciate if someone could explain the pros and cons in depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NS (Stands for NextStep) which is fully object oriented Objective-c and CF (Stands for Core Foundation) which are the C based API's. Memory management is different depending on which framework you are using.

As for performance, unless you really are having performance bottlenecks and you realize about memory management with C, I'll go with Objective-C. Now with its garbage collection pain has gone.

Comment: The memory management isn't different at all. Core FOUNDATION has the same reference counting environment as Foundation.